# meteor template helpers function not working properly

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have 2 functions in Template.meetings.helpers, but only one function is working.

```js
Template.meetings.helpers({
  group: function() {
    console.log('meeting id from helper group = ' + this.meetingId);
    console.log('group id from helper group = ' + this.groupId);
    return Groups.findOne({_id: this.groupId});
  },
  meeting: function() {
    console.log('meeting id from helper meeting = ' + this.meetingId);
    console.log('group id from helper meeting = ' + this.groupId);
    return Meetings.findOne({_id: this.meetingId});
  },
});
```

My console shows the following:

```js
router.js:73 meetingId from router = ZKkLLvdCpRmrF7uXD
router.js:74 groupId from router = xFSzAHBEps2dSKcWM
meetings.js:26 meeting id from helper meeting = ZKkLLvdCpRmrF7uXD
meetings.js:27 group id from helper meeting = xFSzAHBEps2dSKcWM
```

router.js:

```js
Router.route('/meetings/:_id/:groupId?', {
 waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('meeting');
    return Meteor.subscribe('Group');
  },

 action: function () {
    console.log('meetingId from router = ' + this.params._id);
    console.log('groupId from router = ' + this.params.groupId);
   this.render('meetings', {
   data: {
        meetingId: this.params._id,
        groupId: this.params.groupId
   }
  });
 },
  onBeforeAction: function(){
  var currentGroup = Members.find({
      groupId: this.params.groupId,
      memberId: Meteor.userId()
    }).count();
    Session.set('groupId', this.params.groupId);
    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    if(currentUser && currentGroup > 0){
        this.next();
    } else {
        this.render("landingPage");
    }
  }
});
```

I can't figure out why the group: function() is not outputting to the console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible you have something else named group? Possibly a field in the data context from iron router? Try a quick rename of that helper and template call to eliminate a naming issue... Can you share your ir route and html?

Comment: I think they'll not run unless you called them from templates, are you sure you're using that helper somewhere in template?

Comment: @PhilipPryde - Thanks, I did try different names, but it still didn't show in the console.

Comment: Can you share the html template?